# Add classes in Javascript

Tags: javascript

https://jsfiddle.net/3vt7ja9w/
 Can someone help me? I need to make classes in JS so i can style it the same way as the one i have done in css and the one which are the first on site.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
<script src="test.js" defer></script>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="cards">

<div id="div">Div element</div>

<div class="header" id="js-header"><p>output</p></div>

<div class="by">By</div>

<div class="time">20 minutes ago<br>
    <button class="button">View button</button></div>





</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "make classes in JavaScript"?  What are you trying to do, what attempt have you made, and where are you stuck?

Comment: You see the first box that is looking okey in the JS Fiddle?
I need to make the JS code into classes to style the boxes in JS like the one i have made with HTML and CSS. The JS boxes should look exactly the same as the one i have made in html, but i do not know how to make classes on them and style them.

Comment: try looking at this and see if it helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you mean defining styles via JS. You can't define it as CSS classes, but you can do next:

```
const class1 = {
  background: '#000',
  color: '#000',
};

function addClass(el, cls) {
  const style = Object.keys(cls).map(prop => `${prop}: ${cls[prop]}`).join(';');
  Object.assign(el.style, style);
}

addClass(document.getElementById('someEl'), class1);
```

But keep in mind that correct removing styles of specified class is very hard task also this approach is actually a bad practice, so consider defining CSS classes and only add/remove them via JS. For example:

```
// test.css
.someClass {
  background: #000;
  color: #000;
}


// test.js
const el = document.getElementById('someEl');
el.classList.add('someClass');
// ...
el.classList.remove('someClass');
```

Comment: As you say defining CSS classes and add them via JS. How do I do that with the code i already have?

Comment: @KX0 added an example in my answer